# Hash method not providing password that is stored in database

Tags: entities, users

I created a custom form for the registration, but I am not getting how to store the password in hash format in the database.

I am using the following code, but I am not getting the value Drupal saves in the database for the password.

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('password_inc', 'includes/password.inc');
echo user_hash_password('taliadmin');
```

Why am I getting a different value?

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking. You want to put user password, unencrypted, and get the same hash Drupal is getting?

Comment: i want to store password in hash format like drupal do.. so tell me which method i need to use?

Comment: I guess just use the password default field... it will do the job automatically :o

Comment: i created custom module not using defualt signup module of drupa..

Comment: @DeDevelopers Drupal salts it's passwords to make it harder to attack them. It is not easy to replicate this by design.

Comment: so how can i add custom in database. as my form is totally different so that's why i am asking for this @Mołot

Comment: @DeDevelopers yes, but fields are re-usable.

Comment: Any live example you have online with coding? or tutorial.. please send me so i can check

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1063598

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty much the point. [`user_hash_password`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_hash_password/7) uses [`_password_generate_salt`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/_password_generate_salt/7), which in turn uses [`drupal_random_bytes`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_random_bytes/7). This means hash returned will always contain randomization and is designed not to return the same result twice. Or at least do it as rarely as possible, because there is 2^(6*8) possible outputs of 6 random bytes.

To test passwords, Drupal uses [`user_check_password`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_check_password/7). This function extracts salt from stored password and applies it to the one user provided.

Note that by design Drupal does not have any function that would allow to recreate hashes perfectly, and it's not possible to write one (without using original hash to extract salt, that is). You can get pretty close if you need to, copying logic from  [`user_check_password`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_check_password/7), but it is actually better to leave salt changing as much as possible.